# Hide pop up clicking anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to hide pop up clicking anywhere in page, not only when clicking again in "My team"

```
<div class="col-lg-3 mb-0" style="display: flex;align-items: center;">
                <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()"><h6>My team</h6>
                    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">My team members:<br>AAA<br>BBB<br>CCC</span>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <ol class="breadcrumb"></ol>

        <script>
            // When the user clicks on <div>, open the popup
            function myFunction() {
            var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
            popup.classList.toggle("show");
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: depends if the popup is interactive, in other words if there are things to click inside the popup.

Comment: Uhmmm how about this one with 1518 upvotes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Comment: Do you truly mean any where?  Meaning the next click, regardless of where, should close the popup?

Comment: Atually i've checked 1518 votes post and other ones, but not working. Yes Taplar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this code is working. Thanks.

```js
$('.popup').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($('#myPopup').css('display') == 'none')
    $('#myPopup').show();
  else
    $('#myPopup').hide();
});
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  $clicked = $(e.target);
  if(!$clicked.is('.popup') && $('.popup').has(e.target).length==0) {
    $('#myPopup').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3 mb-0" style="display: flex;align-items: center;">
  <div class="popup"><h6>My team</h6>
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">My team members:<br>AAA<br>BBB<br>CCC</span>
  </div>
</div>
<ol class="breadcrumb"></ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {

   $clicked = $(e.target);

   if(!$clicked.is('.popup') && $('.popup').has(e.target).length==0) {
      $('.popup').hide();
   }

});
```

Comment: Pay attention: this code handles elements with the "popup" class. The element with the id "myPopup" does not have this class. Fine tune your HTML or your JavaScript to use the right selectors. The code I posted simply shows the general idea.